# file upload with Ckeditor(Using NodeJs and Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ckeditor

So i wanted to integrate a Ckeditor in my wwebApp. I'm using NodeJs, Express ad Mongoose. I want to have something like a link that goes to a file that's stored in my database

Can't find how to configure my upload file URL. I found this in their website :

```
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php';
```

But i don't understand how to configure the uploader

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I could find a solution by adding upload care. Here's how i did it if it can help someone:

added the Uploadcare plugin from here : https://github.com/uploadcare/uploadcare-ckeditor (Everything is explaned )

added this script:

```
UPLOADCARE_PUBLIC_KEY = 'demopublickey';
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' , {
      extraPlugins: 'uploadcare',
      uploadcare: {
          multiple: true
      }
  });
```

And now i'm very happy :)